# How can i set a ParticleSystem position to touch position?

Tags: unity-game-engine, touch

I want to set a particleSystem position to the first touch position.
I use the code below:

```
public ParticleSystem pSystem;
  Touch firstTouch;

     void LateUpdate(){


    if (Input.touchCount == 1) {    

                firstTouch = Input.GetTouch (0);

                if (firstTouch.phase == TouchPhase.Began) { 

                    pSystem.transform.position = new Vector3 (firstTouch.position.x, firstTouch.position.y, -3);

                    pSystem.Play ();            

                }

            }   

}
```

but the pSystem position does not get the position of the touch. Any idea what i m doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that when you're getting the touch coordinates, they are stored as screen coordinates in the Touch object. If you convert those coordinates to world space, they should be the area in which you're touching in the world. Check out [this link](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint.html) from Unity's documentation that might help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
Vector3 touchWorld = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (new Vector3(firstTouch.position.x, firstTouch.position.y));
pSystem.transform.position = touchWorld;
```